# Troubles with Custom Events

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been having lots of trouble with custom events in as3 recently, I've googled a bunch of stuff that doesn't help and used this tutorial to try to figure them out but I'm still confused.

So I set up a new flash fla file to test them and couldn't figure it out, here is what I have:

document as file:

```
package  

{
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Custom extends MovieClip 
{
    var intializer:Initializer;

    var added:Added;

    public function Custom() 
    {
        intializer=new Initializer();
        addChild(intializer);
        intializer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClicker);
        addEventListener(CustomEvent.EVENT_CUSTOM, OnCatch);
    }

    private function OnClicker(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        added=new Added();
        added.x=300; added.y=300; 
        addChild(added);
    }

    private function OnCatch(event:CustomEvent):void
    {
        trace("hi");
        removeChild(added);
    }
}

}
```

event as file:

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class CustomEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const EVENT_CUSTOM="event1";

        public function CustomEvent(type) 
        {
            super(type, false, false);
        }

    }

}
```

and the movieclips as file:

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Added extends MovieClip 
    {
        var addedButton:AddedButton;

        public function Added() 
        {
            addedButton=new AddedButton();
            addedButton.x=30; addedButton.y=30;
            addChild(addedButton);
            addedButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnClickie);
        }

        private function OnClickie(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.EVENT_CUSTOM));
        }
    }

}
```

Buttons use an empty class, This gives me this result: (top left corner for first button.)
http://www.fastswf.com/_EfGSoQ

Sorry for so much code, but custom events seem to require a lot of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are listening for your custom event in the wrong place. You can address this several ways using event bubbling, the event's capture phase, or by listening for the event on the object that dispatches the event (the event target).

The [Flash Event Model](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html) follows the W3C event model (used in the DOM/Javascript). When an event is dispatched, it goes through three phases: capture phase, target phase, and bubbling phase. It's described in the above link (in the "Event propagation and phases" section).

For performance reasons (my assumption), the capture and bubbling phases are not enabled by default.

**Note you only need to do one of the 3 things below.** I suggest using the event target, it's the easiest to understand. The others have their places and can be very useful, but you can do most everything w/the target phase.

## How to use the target phase

In your document class remove this line from the constructor:

```
addEventListener(CustomEvent.EVENT_CUSTOM, OnCatch);
```

Remove it because we're going to listen for the event coming from the `Added` object directly (it's the event target). To do that change your code that adds the object in the document class:

```
private function OnClicker(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    added=new Added();
    added.x=300; added.y=300; 
    addChild(added);
    added.addEventListener(CustomEvent.EVENT_CUSTOM, OnCatch);
}
```

## How to use the capture phase

In your document class, add an additional parameter when adding the event listener to enable the capture phase:

```
addEventListener(CustomEvent.EVENT_CUSTOM, OnCatch, true);
```

This allows any parent of the event target to handle the event, **before** the target handles it.

## How to use the bubbling phase:

To use the bubbling phase, your custom event object needs to "bubble". So you will need to modify the constructor in your custom event class:

```
public function CustomEvent(type) 
{
    super(type, true, false);
}
```

Here I've changed the second parameter in the call to `super()`, allowing the event to "bubble".

Since the event now bubbles back up the display list, any parent of the event target will also be able to listen for the event **after** the target has handled it.

Comment: Thanks. That was simpler then expected, I wonder why none of the tutorials I read said anything about that...